# Codename One - AutoComplete popup window location

Tags: codenameone

On my GUI built app I am using the AutoComplete TextField for searching for values. After the user taps the "search" button, the AutoComplete appears. When I enter something, it works well, and the popup window appears showing the matched values right at the bottom of the field.

But if I perform another search, the popup window appears further down. On a third search, it appears even further, and on a fourth search, it is gone from the window. I am attaching a screenshot of the third search.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to this bug: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1687 or maybe this one: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1697