# AutoCompleteTextField completion strings display issue

Tags: codenameone

I've made a form in the GUI builder that has 5 auto complete text fields. All are made in exactly the same way with their completion arrays set before the form is shown, also in exactly the same way. The first two fields work as expected. The second two fields only show their completion options after some of the picker components are used on the form (they are in the same container), and the last one never shows completion options (or is showing them off screen?).

Answer (score 0):

This looks related to [Codename One - AutoComplete popup window location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810486/codename-one-autocomplete-popup-window-location) which in turn refers to two open bugs both of which are scheduled for this release cycle:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1687

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1697